# Best way to resolve Typescript/Angular libraries

Tags: angular, typescript, web-worker

I recently added a web worker to my V8 Angular project and it just did not fully work. I have library conflicts as will be shown below. My questions are:

- Does the lib property in tsconfig.json get propagated down to child tsconfig.app.json assuming tsconfig.app.json has "extends": "./tconfig.json". In other words, if I specify lib "dom in tsconfig, does tsconfig.app have it by extension?
- My tsconfig.app.json is used for the main app, and tsconfig.worker.json is used for the web worker. Does tsconfig.app.json lib need webworker, or does tsconfig.worker.json lib need web worker?
- More simply, why does it not find even basic things like Function or Promise and many others despite including esnext, es2015 and others in the lib.
- When I see the linkage errors, which tsconfig file does it apply to?

```
> cd client && ng build --prod --base-href / && cd ../


Date: 2021-08-20T03:32:56.569Z
Hash: f2ec8f4f5a07ae0f3a5b
Time: 11865ms
chunk {main} main-es5.df7d516da5b815bde751.js, main-es5.df7d516da5b815bde751.js.map (main) 667 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills-es5.e7f33e0369a88b3ee7ce.js, polyfills-es5.e7f33e0369a88b3ee7ce.js.map (polyfills) 435 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime-es5.618bcded6741c4c27fdf.js, runtime-es5.618bcded6741c4c27fdf.js.map (runtime) 6.1 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.cc2b720567c4dabe68e6.js, scripts.cc2b720567c4dabe68e6.js.map (scripts) 3.94 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.7cbe70a9f2f210000d3f.css, styles.7cbe70a9f2f210000d3f.css.map (styles) 140 bytes [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(25,1): error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, BlobPart, HeadersInit, BodyInit, RequestInfo, DOMHighResTimeStamp, CanvasImageSource, MessageEventSource, ImageBitmapSource, TimerHandler, PerformanceEntryList, VibratePattern, AlgorithmIdentifier, HashAlgorithmIdentifier, BigInteger, NamedCurve, GLenum, GLboolean, GLbitfield, GLint, GLsizei, GLintptr, GLsizeiptr, GLuint, GLfloat, GLclampf, TexImageSource, Float32List, Int32List, BufferSource, DOMTimeStamp, FormDataEntryValue, IDBValidKey, Transferable, BinaryType, ClientTypes, EndingType, IDBCursorDirection, IDBRequestReadyState, IDBTransactionMode, KeyFormat, KeyType, KeyUsage, NotificationDirection, NotificationPermission, PushEncryptionKeyName, PushPermissionState, ReferrerPolicy, RequestCache, RequestCredentials, RequestDestination, RequestMode, RequestRedirect, ResponseType, ServiceWorkerState, ServiceWorkerUpdateViaCache, VisibilityState, WebGLPowerPreference, WorkerType, XMLHttpRequestResponseType

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(39,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Int8Array'.

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(39,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Int16Array'.

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(39,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Int32Array'.

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(39,47): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Uint8Array'.

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(39,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Uint16Array'.

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(39,74): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Uint32Array'.

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(39,88): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Uint8ClampedArray'.

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(39,108): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Float32Array'.

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(39,123): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Float64Array'.

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(39,138): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DataView'.

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(39,149): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ArrayBuffer'.

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(43,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Int8Array'.

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(43,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Int16Array'.

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(43,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Int32Array'.

... Many more omitted ...
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./out-tsc/worker",
        "lib": ["dom","webworker"], 
        "types": [],
        "module": "ES2015"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "test.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts",
        "**/*.worker.ts"
    ]
}
```

tsconfig.worker.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/worker",
    "lib": ["es2015"],
    "types": [],
    "module": "ES2015"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.worker.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: I think I chose a different module, but not sure anymore.